# registrar and whois database

Tags: whois

do registrars have unlimited access to each other's whois database?  For example, do godaddy have access to network solutions's whois database and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, registrars are limited to their own database and the public data provided by other registrars.

Comment: if that's the case, how come domaintools.com can provide all the data?

Comment: What information is domaintools providing that isn't available from a public source?

Comment: "public data provided by other registrars." Not necessarily true. First, they could be specific arrangements between registrars. Also some registries provide specific whois services (in .DE and .UK for example if I remember correctly) only for registrars.

Answer (score 1):

Registrars can only make CHANGES to things that are registered through them. They can ACCESS any public whois info.